# Issue with shutdown and restart in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, shutdown, freeze

I have recently installed Xubuntu because my Windows 10 was consuming too much RAM and Xubuntu is just amazing but now whenever I press shut down, it starts shutting down and when it gets totally blank, the Xubuntu shutting down screen again appears and and freezes

[image: Frozen screen]

It remains frozen for 1-2 minutes and then completely shuts down. Same problem happens with restarting also.

Is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seams to be problem with new kernel. Removing option "splash" from boot options fixed this for me (you will no longer have splash screen).

You can do it by grub menu (press e on ubuntu option, find kernel options (normaly they are "quiet splash"), and remove word "splash". Then save and see if it gets better.

Alternatively you can remove option quiet as well to see what is going on. There's also a way of speeding up shutdown time by adding a timeout for all processes that won't end for some reason (for me freeze was 5-10 seconds, so your 2 minutes seam bit excesive, maybe there's more than one thing going on): https://itsfoss.com/long-shutdown-linux/